# Sublime Text 3 Windows column selection with Alt?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

**<kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click** feels unintuitive to me.

How can I tell ST3 to allow **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + drag** to do column selection, like in many other programs?

Comment: Does the middle mouse button not already do that?

Comment: It does, but I'm looking for Alt+drag functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this to work on Windows 7 using Sublime Text 3.

I created a file "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap", and put this in it:

```
[
  {
    "button": "button1","modifiers": ["alt"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
  },
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the portable version and placed it in "Sublime Text\Data\Packages\User", and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by `dwn` is correct, but it is not complete answer.

This is more complex, because sometimes you need select two columns or just unselect some.
You need something like this:

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt", "shift"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1", "modifiers": ["alt", "ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
    }
]
```

*Tested on Win 7 and Sublime Text 3*