# How can I change the mouse binding of "Add cursor" in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Currently, to select multiple cursors in Sublime Text 3, you have to hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and left click. I want to change the mouse binding of that. Instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, I want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I know how to change the mouse binding in Sublime Text 3. It is to create file *Username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap*

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "count": 1,
        "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "command_here"
    }
]
```

I don't know what command should I put in there. I found the command list in https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html, but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you sure you really need a command other than drag_select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some googling and testing, I solved my own problem.  Here's the code that I placed

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "count": 1,
        "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"additive": true}
    }
]
```

Comment: I added your code to `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` and but it is not adding cursor. Currently it drags/extends 'Selection' rather than cursor. Trying to extend cursor down a column. JUST FOUND how here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27788553/913295